# How to access a file in a different folder with kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, file-io, filepath

thanks for any help you provide in advance.

I have a basic function meant to print out each line in a file.

```
fun printFile() {
         File("Test.txt").forEachLine { println(it) } 
}
```

When I do this, the file must be in the folder for the project. Such that

[F[ Project

- [F] .idea
- [F] out
- [F[ src

  - - Main.kt
- Test.txt

How can I make it so that I can put the .txt file in another location, like below.

[F[ Project

- [F] .idea
- [F] out
- [F[ texts

  - - Test.txt
- [F[ src

  - - Main.kt

Read:

[F] <- Closed Folder

[F[ <- Open Folder

- <- The following is in a folder
- -<- The following is in a folder that's in a folder

Comment: That just depends on the current directory set, which in this case is your project's path. So for the example you gave, you would do `File("texts/Test.txt")`. But I'm sure that's not really what you're trying to do, can you be more specific on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes actually it was exactly that. I just wasn't sure how to start it if I should do (Texts"test.txt" or otherwise. Thank you so much! I also couldn't find any good online resources for it and I found out about thing thing called file tree walking...